# Netty 4 - Outbound message at head of pipeline discarded

Tags: java, netty

I am using Netty 4 RC1. I initialize my pipeline at the client side:

```
public class NodeClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

  @Override
  protected void initChannel(SocketChannel sc) throws Exception {
    // Frame encoding and decoding
    sc.pipeline()
      .addLast("logger", new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))

    // Business logic
      .addLast("handler", new NodeClientHandler());
  }
}
```

NodeClientHandler has the following relevant code:

```
public class NodeClientHandler extends ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter {
  private void sendInitialInformation(ChannelHandlerContext c) {
    c.write(0x05);
  }

  @Override
  public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext c) throws Exception {
    sendInitialInformation(c);
  }
}
```

I connect to the server using:

```
  public void connect(final InetSocketAddress addr) {
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    ChannelFuture cf = null;
    try {
      // set up the pipeline
      bootstrap.group(new NioEventLoopGroup())
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .handler(new NodeClientInitializer());

      // connect
      bootstrap.remoteAddress(addr);
      cf = bootstrap.connect();
      cf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture op) throws Exception {
          logger.info("Connect to {}", addr.toString());
        }
      });

      cf.channel().closeFuture().syncUninterruptibly();
    } finally {
      bootstrap.shutdown();
    }
  }
```

So, what I basically want to do is to send some initial information from the client to the server, after the channel is active (i.e. the connect was successful). However, when doing the `c.write()` I get the following warning and no package is send:

```
WARNING: Discarded 1 outbound message(s) that reached at the head of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.
```

I know there is no outbound handler in my pipeline, but I didn't think I need one (at this point) and I thought Netty would take care to transport the ByteBuffer over to the server. What am I doing wrong here in the pipeline configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netty only handle messages of type ByteBuf by default if you write to the Channel. So you need to wrap it in a ByteBuf. See also the Unpooled class with its static helpers to create ByteBuf instances.